# Does mysql 5.6 support the [ with.. as() ] syntax?

Tags: mysql

[navicat picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgrIf.png)

```
with detail as(
select id,end_time,status from t_wl_record_repairs_detail where end_time is null
)
select COUNT(1) as sum, 'today' as name from detail where end_time is not null and end_time >= '2021-02-04 00:00:00' and `status` > 2
UNION
select COUNT(1) , 'd1' as name from detail where end_time is not null and end_time < '2021-02-04 00:00:00' and `status` < 3
UNION
select COUNT(1), 'd7' as name from detail where end_time is not null and end_time < '2021-01-29 00:00:00' and `status` < 3
UNION
select COUNT(1), 'd30' as name from detail where end_time is not null and end_time < '2021-01-06 00:00:00' and `status` < 3;
```

I want to write sql like this,but it didn't work.Does mysql 5.6 support the [ with.. as() ] syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (the name of the `WITH` clause) were introduced in MySQL 8. They cannot be used in 5.6. Instead we typically would join subqueries in older MySQL versions.

For a query like yours where you are reusing the same common table expression across several `UNION` components, instead of a subquery I would recommend selecting it into a temporary table which you then use in your `UNION` query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE detail 
  SELECT id, end_time, status
  FROM t_wl_record_repairs_detail
  WHERE end_time IS NULL;

SELECT COUNT(1) as sum, 'today' as name FROM detail...
UNION
SELECT COUNT(1) as sum, 'd1' as name....
UNION...
```

### Update:

MySQL [has documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html) that temporary tables cannot be referenced more than once, such as in a `UNION`.

This still might be doable with a clever chain of `CASE` and no temporary table or CTE.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) AS sum,
  CASE 
    WHEN end_time end_time >= '2021-02-04 00:00:00' and `status` > 2 THEN 'today'
    WHEN end_time < '2021-02-04 00:00:00' and `status` < 3 THEN 'd1'
    WHEN end_time < '2021-01-29 00:00:00' and `status` < 3 THEN 'd7'
    WHEN end_time < '2021-01-06 00:00:00' and `status` < 3 THEN 'd30'
    ELSE 'other'
  END AS name
FROM t_wl_record_repairs_detail
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: thank you very much. I will use the temporary table as you suggest

Comment: I have a problem with temp tables: you can only look up a temp table once in the same query statement.
like:

mysql> SELECT * FROM temp_table, temp_table AS t2;
ERROR 1137: Can't reopen table: 'temp_table'

There is a 1137 error here.
i quit.../手动滑稽

Comment: @bestliuxingtang Try the `CASE` chain I just posted. I believe that should work.

Comment: I can not believe that this can be done, too awesome, thank you